# What brand of front shocks would you recommend for 2004 Cadillac Escalade 2WD?

Tags: suspension, cadillac, escalade, shock-absorber

I have a 2004 Cadillac Escalade 2WD V8 5.3L (215K miles). I'm looking at replacing the front shocks myself, and was wondering how to intelligently select a good replacement for them?

Comment: You will probably want to rephrase the question around "how to select a replacement" rather than "which should I buy." Why not use OEM parts?

Comment: If you're replacing them yourself you're likely best off going with a "complete assembly" rather than having to deal with a spring compressor etc. Providing your time is worth more than money.

Answer (score 0):

That question is rather subjective, but I'll give an opinion on a set of shocks that I have used.

I own a 2003 Chevrolet Suburban RWD and purchased Monroe 911505 Reflex Monotube Shock Absorbers.  Obviously you'll want to double check that they'll fit, but I would imagine they do.  It'll mainly depend on whether you have electronic suspension or not.

Granted, I purchased the vehicle with about 140k miles on it, so I can't really give an opinion on a comparison between brand new OEM and aftermarket.  However, I can say that the difference between the OEM with 140k on them and the Monroes is night and day.  I can almost guarantee that it'll make it ride like a Cadillac...  Ha.  Monroe has been around for quite a long time, with a reputable name for the most part, and the price isn't a killer either.

So in case you hadn't come across those yet, I would add them to your list of possibilities.  Good luck.

Comment: Bent plastic would probably out-perform shocks at 140k...

Comment: Funny guy. :p   I've had shocks last almost 200k.  Replaced them and had almost no difference from old to new.  Maybe that was an outlier, but it showed me that it's possible.  Shocking...

Comment: @TravisThomas Shocks are funny that way, I have had them go out at 40K or less and others go for the life of the vehicle. I suppose it has to do with road conditions in the area it is driven.

Comment: @Moab  Agreed.  I'm sure there are too many factors to even try to consider.  Luck of the draw (quality control) very well may be a considerable part of it, too.