# Replacing OEM Shocks in 2004 Cadillac Escalade with Z55 Auto Ride Suspension

Tags: suspension, cadillac, shock-absorber

I have a 2004 Cadillac Escalade 2WD 5.3L V8 with Z55 Autoride Suspension. The ride quality is pretty rough, so I'm trying to do everything I can to smooth it out. I was just going to replace the front two shocks with standard OEM gas shocks (but they are not compatible with Autoride setup). Is it okay to replace electronic shocks with gas shocks (if even possible)? I've seen people say that it would still work, but all Autoride features would not work. The main reason I am asking is because of the cost, replacement for one shock looks to be $250. The Autoride system in my vehicle hasn't worked in a long time, so I'm wondering if it's even worth it to get shocks that work with Autoride.

Comment: Similar to https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/53293/10976

Comment: Do you know if it's the Autoride system which is at fault or just the shocks? They are sort of integral to each other, right?

Comment: @SolarMike more than similar. I edited that question and voted to re-open but got no support to re-open, so the user gave up and started another question about the same subject, can't blame them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are kits available that replace the electronically-adjustable shocks with standard shocks. They typically come with a couple of small modules that connect to the vehicle’’s wiring harness and trick the computer into thinking the adjustable shocks are still present, so you don’t have to deal with a warning light or message.

If you can live with the warning light, just get the non-Z55 shocks from the same year Escalade, Tahoe or Yukon. It’ll work fine.

I’m dealing with the same quandary on a 2007 Escalade. All of my research indicates that this isn’t really a problem unless you want to keep the adjustability.